# Force restarting / alert CMD application if it stops working

Tags: php, cmd, scheduled-tasks, windows-server

This question is not directly related to PHP. The situation is, I have a scheduled PHP CLI task that runs every after 2 Mins (report generator). Sometimes, Windows encounters the error that CLI stopped working. When it is stopped, it does not execute the new task until we press "close" button on the dialogue box.

Is there anyway that it could be "closed" or the tasks could be restarted automatically ?
Or even if it can trigger some alert to email so admin can be notified.

Thanks

Comment: Maybe you can use AutoIt to press enter on the keyboard every so often.  The window in focus should close if it is waiting for an OK.

Answer (score 0):

I had the same problem with an cli application on windows. Couldnt find a solve to prevent the crash, eventually i create a batch script that ran every 30 min and killed all php process, which forced my loop to restart.

Heres an example of my .bat file

```
:loop
taskkill /f /im php.exe
taskkill /f /im php.exe
taskkill /f /im php.exe
@ping 127.0.0.1 -n 1800 -w 1000 > nul
goto loop
```

The ping in the code is the way i make the script sleep. Its also worth mentioning that the script that called my php was also a bat file, so it wasnt killed when the above was run. Hense restarting the loop.

Heres what i mean:

```
:loop
c:\php\php.exe D:\somedir\somescript.php
goto loop
```

So the first is to restart the loop, in case of a app crash. The Second is what actually makes the php script run in the first place

Hope this helps.

Answer (score 0):

I have a solution for this problem.

First create a .bat file:

```
php -q -f script.php
```

save as batch.bat

and then create new task with windows scheduler with these settings :

**General:**
 1. Run whether user is logged on or not
 2. Run with higest privileges
 3. List item

**Triggers**

1. Begin the task: at task creation/modification
2. Repeat task every: 1 Minute for indefinitely
3. enabled

**Actions**

- Browse and select batch.bat

**Settings**

1. Allow task to be run on demand
2. Run task as soon as possible
3. if the task fails, restart every: 1 Minute
4. **Do not start a new instance**

Click OK and type password for Administrator